# How to config Channel A/B of FTDI FT4232H to JTAG

Tags: stm32, jtag, ftdi

I'm new with FT4232H. I just make for myself a FT4232H device with 4 channels UART. (Custom board for learning and researching)

And I want change channel A and B to JTAG for debugging STM32 using JTAG line.

My first question: Is FT4232H will automatically detect when I use JTAG? If not, how can I config it? If yes, is there anything I should do before it for it? (I have EEPROM in my FT4232H board)

My second question: How can I debug STM32 with JTAG using FT4232H? (I use STMCubeIDE).

Comment: You need a program which can provide a debug server to CubeIde side and can talk JTAG through FT4232 to target. Do you have such a program? Can OpenOCD do that?

Comment: @Justme I'm new to JTAG and don't use anything related to JTAG so I just do it by myself with it, l used SWD for a long time. The last time I read somewhere in ethernet it said it can do that. In CubeIDE it has the option for JTAG but it doesn't seem to work with FT4232H.

Comment: You need a piece of software between CubeIde and FT4323. CubeIde can use several pieces of debug servers and these debug servers may use any hardware they want or support to access the MCU.

Answer (score 0):

The FT4232H [datasheet](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT4232H.pdf) contains the following in section *4.4 MPSSE Interface Mode Description*:

> MPSSE Mode is designed to allow the FT4232H to interface efficiently with synchronous serial protocols such as JTAG, I2C and SPI Bus. It can also be used to program SRAM based FPGA’s over USB. The MPSSE interface is designed to be flexible so that it can be configured to allow any synchronous serial protocol (industry standard or proprietary) to be implemented using the FT4232H. MPSSE is only available on channel A and channel B.
>
> MPSSE is fully configurable, and is programmed by sending commands down the data stream. These can be sent individually or more efficiently in packets. MPSSE is capable of a maximum sustained data rate of 30 Mbits/s.

The datasheet contains links to:

1. [Application Note AN_108 Command Processor for MPSSE and MCU Host Bus Emulation Modes](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_108_Command_Processor_for_MPSSE_and_MCU_Host_Bus_Emulation_Modes.pdf), which describes the MPSSE commands which can be used for JTAG.
2. [Application Note AN_110 Programmers Guide for High Speed FTCJTAG DLL](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_110_Programmers_Guide_for_High_Speed_FTCJTAG_DLL.pdf) which has the following in the introduction:

   > The FTCJTAG DLL has been created to allow application developers to use the FT2232D, FT2232H and FT4232H devices to create a USB to Joint Test Action Group(JTAG) protocol interface without any knowledge of the MPSSE command set. All of the functions in FTCJTAG.DLL can be replicated using calls to FTD2XX.DLL and sending the appropriate commands to the MPSSE.

Where the above two should provide enough information to allow JTAG to be used, either by calling the FTDI `FTCJTAG.DLL` or at a lower level to send the raw MPSSE commands over USB.

As for configuration of the FT4232H EEPROM, [Application Note
AN_124 User Guide for FTDI FT_PROG Utility](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/AN_124_User_Guide_For_FT_PROG.pdf) doesn't list a specific configuration option to select JTAG, but in section *5.9 FT4232H Hardware_Specific* does contain:

> Each channel can also be individually configured in synchronous or asynchronous bit-bang mode. See the FT4232H device datasheet (available from the [Datasheets](http://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/DataSheets.htm) page of the [FTDI website](http://www.ftdichip.com/)) for more information on these modes.

I don't have a FT4232H to hand, so can't run `FT_PROG` to confirm what options there are related to the MPSSE mode in the EEPROM settings.